# Future images in my upload directory don't have the correct permission

Tags: symfony, file-upload, file-permissions

I'm using symfony2 framework in an application and it works fine. I'm having a problem on deployment though:

I have an upload directory in my testing area. The directory is web/uploads/images. This folder has the following permission: 700. However, each time I upload a new image in there, the permission on the image is 600. This means that the image won't show on my application. Of course, when I then set the permission manually on the newly uploaded image, it shows correctly.

I try using the umask but it didn't really work. My guess is that maybe I need to do something on symfony2 when I upload the image.

Thanks for your answer

Comment: `This folder has the following permission: 700`. Are you referring to the chmod permission here?

Comment: Yes. Actually, I even tried the chmod permission 777. But it doesn't work. Everny new images have the permission 600 when they come in the folder.

Comment: are you uploading image with class UploadedFile ?

Comment: Yes that's what I use: the class Uploaded File

Answer (score 0):

you need to use umask as the user that you're running the symofony application as.

look here:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html

Comment: Thank you. I already went through this post. May be I'm doing something wrong. I tried to enter the exact following command for my uploads folder: umask 0000. But the images still doesn't have the correct permission. You are talking of a user though. How do I know which user I'm using?

Comment: When you set up a server you set up php to be run as a certain user, be that root or another user you dictate.  You need to use umask as the user that is running the inatance of php.  You can use ps -ef to see what user is running php.

Answer (score 0):

Use symfony filesystem component [link](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/filesystem.html) . After moving the image to the directory use chmod from the above component and set the needed permissions to the moved image.